# How should I use the Back Stack to allow usage of the back button?

Tags: android, android-activity, subactivity

So, I have this app with 4 different activities:

- A is the main activity with three buttons to launch B, C and D (I think people use to refer to these as sub activities).
- Each activity has its own layout, but I believe that this is not relevant
  here.

What I want to do is the standard behaviour for most apps. That is:

1. I start by launching the app and seeing activity A.
2. Then I press a button, C, for instance, and activity C is shown.
3. Then I press the back button and activity A is shown again.

My app does points 1 and 2 correctly, but on 3 the app disappears.

The onClick method of the buttons has something like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this,C.class));
```

None of the activities overrides the onBackPressed method.

Here is (part of) my manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".A" android:label="A" android:launchMode="standard" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".B" android:label="B" android:launchMode="standard" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
<activity android:name=".C" android:label="C" android:launchMode="standard" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
<activity android:name=".D" android:label="D" android:launchMode="standard" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

I know from debug work I've done, that A.onDestroy() is called after the onClick method of a button is called.
Based on this info, I think that, and of course I might be wrong, activity A is removed from history stack by the OS for some reason.

Now I know that this kind of issue has already been addressed here on stackoverflow, but I've tried all the suggestions I could find and none worked.
I wanted to explain my own case.

Comment: if A.onDestroy() is called there is no way of getting A back in the activity stack (except for calling A manually, but it will not be at the right place in the stack). what do you do in onPause() ? did you override that?

Comment: The A Activity should be in the stack. Do you use finish() when you start the new activity? I used this a lot and the only thing that did this was setting the noHistory property in the manifest. I never used android:launchMode="standard" but it doesn't look like this closes the  activity

Comment: @stefan I do not override onPause. I do override onResume (it is where I inflate the layout). I got it working by doing what you said, calling A manually, but it is not anywhere near elegance...

Comment: maybe it's just developer options. in the emulator you can have the option "only one activity" enabled which forces all unused activities to be destroyed. have you tried it on a phone or the emulator? is it a debug build or not?

Comment: @colegu I do not use finish().

Comment: @stefan I am debugging the app on a phone. The manifest has android:debuggable="false" if that is what you mean by debug build.

Answer (score 0):

Of course that I should be doing something wrong.

I was overriding the onWindowFocusChanged method and destroying the activity there, so of course it was being removed from the stack.

I am sorry for wasting your time @stefan and @colegu.